# How to check how long AC adapter has been connected

Tags: charging

Is there any way to check how long a 2020 M1 MacBook Pro has been connected to an AC adapter? (I have a charger that I think is periodically disconnecting and reconnecting.)

I'd like something like Terminal "uptime" but for this purpose it'd print something, for example, "On AC Adapter for H hours M minutes).

Comment: Why is this important info to have?  The SMC (what handles charging) will connect and disconnect mains periodically to maintain a certain level of charge in the battery especially when “optimized charging” is enabled.  What this means is, you could potentially get a message that it was on mains for 5 minutes and it has full charge.  What problem are you looking to solve?

Comment: I think my charger is disconnecting/reconnecting. I hear the occasional beep from the laptop like it's being plugged in again. I'd like to confirm before I "retire" the charger - it is a nice one.

Comment: Check your household current first.  Plug into a UPS and if that behavior stops, you’re having small power drops or brown outs.  If it continues, then you likely have a bad charger.  Confirm by trying a different charger; even an inexpensive one.

Answer (score 1):

## pmset

Use the built-in macOS command line tool [`pmset`](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/pmset/) to see a log of power events. The log should include switches to and from AC power:

```
pmset -g log
```